# Loops for filter and replace outliers

Tags: r, loops

I want to know how to write a loop on my dataset on repeat filters:

My sample dataset1:

```
df=  structure(list(system = c("1-Jan-16", "2-Jan-16", "3-Jan-16", 
    "4-Jan-16"), evi1500 = c(0.437, 0.408, 0.429, NA), evi21500 = c(0.3891771, 
    0.38915543, 0.389133761, 0.389112091), kndvi1500 = c(0.493, 0.471, 
    0.769, 0.223), ndvi1500 = c(0.261, 0.698, 0.645, 0.627), nirv1500 = c(0.444426458, 
    0.444472048, 0.444517639, 0.444563229), evi2500 = c(0.366, 0.33, 
    0.367, 0.608), evi22500 = c(0.74, 0.241, 0.424, 0.398), kndvi2500 = c(0.41, 
    0.384, 0.684, 0.173), ndvi2500 = c(0.474621566, 0.474655555, 
    0.474689544, 0.474723532), nirv2500 = c(0.362, 0.596, 0.145, 
    0.442)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

code1

```
outliersevi1500=hampel_outlier(df$evi1500,k_mad_value = 3)
outliersevi1500
outliersevi21500=hampel_outlier(df$evi21500,k_mad_value = 3)
outliersevi21500
outlierskndvi1500=hampel_outlier(df$kndvi1500,k_mad_value = 3)
outlierskndvi1500
df$evi1500[df$evi1500 < 0.1992968  | df$evi1500 >  0.5907032 ] <- NA
df$evi21500[df$evi21500 < 0.2243160  | df$evi21500 >  0.5534532 ] <- NA
df$kndvi1500[df$kndvi1500 < 0.1596835  | df$kndvi1500 >  0.7749794 ] <- NA
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have different filter criteria. This is not just repeated application of a function to many rows. Do you want to apply `hampel_outlier` only to the 3 columns menationed or just every column containing having `1500` in their name?

Comment: I want to apply `hampel_outlier` to the ten columns in my dataset for names containing `1500` and `2500`. @danlooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hampel_outlier` returns upper and lower limits for outlier detection. Values outside this interval should be removed by setting their value to `NA`. Invervals are determined for each column of `df` individually. This filtering should be only applied to columns having either `1500` or `2500` in thier name.

Then you can calculate your thresholds and do the outlier replacement like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(funModeling)
#> Loading required package: Hmisc
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: survival
#> Loading required package: Formula
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     src, summarize
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units
#> funModeling v.1.9.4 :)
#> Examples and tutorials at livebook.datascienceheroes.com
#>  / Now in Spanish: librovivodecienciadedatos.ai

df <- structure(list(system = c(
  "1-Jan-16", "2-Jan-16", "3-Jan-16",
  "4-Jan-16"
), evi1500 = c(0.437, 0.408, 0.429, NA), evi21500 = c(
  0.3891771,
  0.38915543, 0.389133761, 0.389112091
), kndvi1500 = c(
  0.493, 0.471,
  0.769, 0.223
), ndvi1500 = c(0.261, 0.698, 0.645, 0.627), nirv1500 = c(
  0.444426458,
  0.444472048, 0.444517639, 0.444563229
), evi2500 = c(
  0.366, 0.33,
  0.367, 0.608
), evi22500 = c(0.74, 0.241, 0.424, 0.398), kndvi2500 = c(
  0.41,
  0.384, 0.684, 0.173
), ndvi2500 = c(
  0.474621566, 0.474655555,
  0.474689544, 0.474723532
), nirv2500 = c(
  0.362, 0.596, 0.145,
  0.442
)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

thresholds <-
  df %>%
  pivot_longer(-system) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(outlieres = hampel_outlier(value, k_mad_value = 3) %>% list()) %>%
  deframe()

df %>%
  mutate(across(matches("1500|2500"), ~ {
    (
      .x < thresholds[[cur_column()]][["bottom_threshold"]] |
      .x > thresholds[[cur_column()]][["top_threshold"]]
    ) %>%
      ifelse(NA, .x)
  })) %>%
  pivot_wider()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 11
#>   system evi1500 evi21500 kndvi1500 ndvi1500 nirv1500 evi2500 evi22500 kndvi2500
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 1-Jan…   0.437    0.389     0.493   NA        0.444   0.366    0.74      0.41 
#> 2 2-Jan…   0.408    0.389     0.471    0.698    0.444   0.33     0.241     0.384
#> 3 3-Jan…   0.429    0.389     0.769    0.645    0.445   0.367    0.424     0.684
#> 4 4-Jan…  NA        0.389     0.223    0.627    0.445  NA        0.398     0.173
#> # … with 2 more variables: ndvi2500 <dbl>, nirv2500 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you please help me with another question? I also want to write another loop for a smooth process. Thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276439/loop-for-savitzky-golay-filters   @danlooo